# Split string every n characters but without splitting a word

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, split, tokenize

Let's suppose that I have this in `python`:

```
orig_string = 'I am a string in python'
```

and if we suppose that I want to split this string every 10 characters but without splitting a word then I want to have this:

```
strings = ['I am a ', 'string in ', 'python']
```

or this (without the whitespaces at the splittings):

```
strings = ['I am a', 'string in', 'python']
```

Therefore, the split should be done exactly before the word which would have been splitted otherwise at each case.

Otherwise, I would have this:

```
false_strings = ['I am a str', 'ing in pyt', 'hon']
```

Just to mention that in my case I want to do this every 15k characters but I gave the example above for every 10 characters so that it could be written in a concise way here.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: What happens if a single word is greater than 10 characters long?

Comment: @shash678, thank you for your question. I answered it at my edited post.

Comment: `textwrap.wrap(orig_string, 10)` *almost* does what you want; the only difference is that is removes the space on which the original string gets split, returning `['I am a', 'string in', 'python']`.

Comment: @chepner, yes I do not necessarily care about these specific whitespaces.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit: if you really care about whitespaces, I don't think the accepted answer answers that.

Comment: @Austin thanks for the remark but I actually think that I do not.

Comment: Fair enough. I read your previous comment without *"not"* part.

Comment: @Austin no worries :)

Comment: Well, you could use `false_strings = [orig_string[y - x:y] for y in range(x, len(orig_string) + x, x)]` determining that `x= 10` the output is `['I am a str', 'ing in pyt', 'hon']`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use built-in `textwrap.wrap` function ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap)):

```
orig_string = 'I am a string in python'

from textwrap import wrap

print(wrap(orig_string, 10))
```

Prints:

```
['I am a', 'string in', 'python']
```

Comment: when 2 people have already suggested this in the comments is it good *etiquette* to write an answer?

Comment: I didn't check the comments. It just popped up from my head (because I use it casi every day)

Comment: I wrote it in comments because I can't write a full answer right now. So it's ok for me

Comment: @OlivierMelançon yah i don't have a strong view, i'd probably make the answer "community wiki" in this case

Comment: I ready don't mind as long as we end up with a quality answer on top

Comment: @Chris_Rands I don't think this is a misstep in *etiquette*. Answers belong in the answer section where they can be voted on and selected.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: It's very important to post answers as actual answers, even if comments may have already mentioned them. I came here via the search engine. Both SO and Google search engines will only find questions and answers, they ignore comments. If you search on `[python] split n characters textwrap` it'll find the answer. (The etiquette of which user deserves rep is separate issue.)